# PHP Countdown from Day Hour Minute Second

Tags: php, countdown

Want to show a countdown of Days Left, Hour, Minute, Second.

The time data comes in this format:

startTime: "2017-02-17T13:51:13",

I found a example script found on stack:

```
<?php
 $now  = new DateTime();
 $ends = new DateTime('May 31, 2017, 11:59 pm'); 
 $left = $now->diff($ends);
?>


<dd>
<div class="timer_wrp">Remaining
    <ul class="timer countdown">
        <li><i><?php echo $left->format('%a'); ?></i>Day</li>
        <li><i><?php echo $left->format('%h'); ?></i>Hour</li>
        <li><i><?php echo $left->format('%i'); ?></i>Min</li>
        <li><i><?php echo $left->format('%s'); ?></i>Sec</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

The Date format is different, is there a easy way to use how its currently setup or would I have to change that into the example format? And do you see anything that maybe missing from this example? Thanks

Comment: Instead of correcting your php change, I cann't resist to advice you to look at front end approach... https://momentjs.com/

Comment: Ok so I feel dumb now, the short date format works instead of the other format. I dont have to convert anything.

Answer (score 2):

check this. If you don't set the time zone your calculation may be wrong. Because, by default it takes the server time zone. It might have other solution but in my case, I always use javascript.

```
<?php

date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Calcutta");
$now  = new DateTime();
$ends = new DateTime('Oct 9, 2020, 4:40:00'); 
$left = $now->diff($ends);
?>


<div class="timer">

<p>Remaining </p>
<ul class="timer countdown">
    
    <li><i><?php echo $left->format('%a'); ?></i>Day</li>
    <li><i><?php echo $left->format('%h'); ?></i>Hour</li>
    <li><i><?php echo $left->format('%i'); ?></i>Min</li>
    <li><i><?php echo $left->format('%s'); ?></i>Sec</li>
    
</ul>
</div>
```

You may need this one also. This one is written in javascript. Copy both and see the difference.

```
<p id="demo"></p>
<!--javascript-->
<script>
// Set the date we're counting down to
var countDownDate = new Date("Oct 9, 2020 4:40:00").getTime();

// Update the count down every 1 second
var x = setInterval(function() {

// Get today's date and time
var now = new Date().getTime();

// Find the distance between now and the count down date
var distance = countDownDate - now;

// Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

// Output the result in an element with id="demo"
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = days + "d " + hours + "h "
+ minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";

// If the count down is over, write some text 
if (distance < 0) {
clearInterval(x);
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "EXPIRED";
}
}, 1000);
</script>
```